# Ubuntu 16.04 suddenly doesen't detect any hardware adapter

Tags: 16.04, hardware, adapter

this is my first question so i hope i'm gonna do it well, also english is not my native language so i hope i'll make myself clear with the less typos/errors possible .

I'm on an Aspire One 721, it's a 7 year Old laptop but so far with various Ubuntu versions It did great.
Last wednesday i decided to upgrade from Ubuntu 14.04, so i formatted my HD and i made a fresh installation of Ubuntu 16.04 (Yes i jump from One LTS to another).

the first week was great, i even noticed performance improvements , but today when i turned It on i got stuck with a 4:3 screen (ofc laptop is 16:9) and i can't even change the resolution because it's the only possible choice.
Other symptoms are that :

-It doesen't output audio in any way (built in speakers, or via aux cable)

- It doesen't detect wireless and ethernet adapters (i tried to connect It to the router but didn't work out)
- it doesen't wake up after suspension , it actually boot but there's no video output.

All of the above functions worked great until yesterday, but since todat none of them work.
Seems like It doesen't detect any hardware adapter of my laptop. 
Of course I already tried to reboot several times without success.

Even if , i think the only way is to reinstall it again, i Hope some of you have an hint or something , i'd really appreciate that. Thank you all!!

TLDR : 1 week Old fresh new installation of Ubuntu 16.04 that was working fine, just stopped detecting any hardware adapter of my laptop including the monitor (it applys standard 4:3 resolution) , wireless,ethernet and audio. Now when it wakes up from suspend it won't output video on the screen. Every or the above worked great until yesterday